# MPI_Recv behavior

Tags: c, mpi

I´m making a MPI application using C and I'm stuck in some problems..

I have something like this:

```
if (rank == 0)
{
    toRank = 1;
    for(i=3;i<=k;i++)
    {
        MPI_Send(&result, 1, MPI_INT, toRank, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        printf(%d\n", result);

        MPI_Recv(&result, 1, MPI_INT, toRank, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        printf("%d\n", result);

        toRank++;
        if (toRank >= numProcessos)
            toRank = 1;
    }
}
else
{
    MPI_Recv(&k, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    printf("%d\n", k);

    MPI_Send(&result, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
}
```

But when master node will send another message for rank 1, this node never receive the message.

Anything wrong with this code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by 'another message'? Your nodes (except for master) receive just one message, you implement it like this.

Comment: For example: master node sends X to node 1.. and then.. after some time.. master have to send another value to node 1.. but after the first message.. node 1 can´t receive any.. the "printf" after worker node MPI_Recv never appears

Comment: In your code the `else` part only receives one message, that is how you programmed it. the "master" node however is able to send multiple messages, which will not be received, as there is no process waiting for them

Comment: Is that caused by the second parameter of MPI_Recv? (1)? What should I do? Increase that number? But if I don´t know the number of processes that a worker node can receive?

Comment: Another point: master node can´t receive 2 messages at the same time with this code?

Comment: no, the second parameter of `MPI_Recv()` only states what the maximum length of a message may be. If you want to have your nodes wait for more messages you have to wrap them in some kind of loop (just like you did with the master node), repeating that step again. Also the master node cannot receive two messages at once using `MPI_Recv()` as you have to specify the sender (`toRank` in your case) and it is a blocking function, waiting until it received a message before proceeding

Comment: Is there any way to configure the master node a receive for any process? So I don´t have to wait for the entire process of a node

Comment: There are various ways of doing that, however that is getting off topic. You may want to look into `MPI_Gather()` and `MPI_Irecv()` read their documentation, maybe find some examples online and then decide which one is better suited for your application

Comment: Receiving from any rank is possible - just specify `MPI_ANY_SOURCE` as rank of the sender in `MPI_Recv` or `MPI_Irecv`. The actual rank could then be obtained by examining the `MPI_SOURCE` field of the output status argument.